# JQuery Accordion Tabs + Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-ui-accordion

If you have a Datatable (with sortable table headers) inside of a JQuery Accordion tab, what is the best way to simulate clicking a specific table header the moment the user opens the Accordion tab to view your table?

Since the Datatable's width and other relevant info isn't actually calculated until the accordion is viewed (thereby showing the Datatable for the first time at that point), I feel the use of fnAdjustColumnSizing() is required, but that alone doesn't simulate clicking on a specific column of in the table header.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  Write what you are trying to accomplish and show some code.  To simulate clicking a header use this on the header selector

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {

  ("#selector").simulate("click");

});
```

Edit:

```
$('selector').trigger('click')
```

Comment: Your code won't do anything. `$('selector').trigger('click')` is what you were looking for.